# Zoom in multiple Areas and Axis Y

Tags: c#, charts, axis, series, area

I have a project with multiple AxisY, with 3 series and and each series has its axisY associated. When I zoom, I have achieved that all the series have zoom but the scale of the axisYof the secondary axisY doesn't change, only that of the main series changes.

Original Chart:
[image: Original chart]

Chart with zoom applied:
[image: Chart with zoom, only changes scale of principal axis]

I have create the new axisY secondary with the code of microsoft (Project "Windows Forms Samples Environment for Microsoft Chart Control"):

```
public void CreateYAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
{
    // Create new chart area for original series
    ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
    areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
    areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
    areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;


    series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

    // Create new chart area for axis
    ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisY_" + series.ChartArea);
    areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
    areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());

    // Create a copy of specified series
    Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
    seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
    foreach(DataPoint point in series.Points)
    {
        seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
    }

    // Hide copied series
    seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
    seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

    // Disable drid lines & tickmarks
    areaAxis.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
    areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
    areaAxis.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font;

    // Adjust area position
    areaAxis.Position.X -= axisOffset;
    areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.X += labelsSize;

}
```

**UPDATE--------------------------------**:

I have this news:

[image]

Now, the 3 axis update his scale but it comes out together, How to separate them?

The code is here:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[2].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;
chart1.ChartAreas[2].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
chart1.ChartAreas[2].AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea1";

chart1.ChartAreas[4].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All;
chart1.ChartAreas[4].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
chart1.ChartAreas[4].AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea1";
```

Comment: How do you zoom?

Comment: assigning the extra areas to the main area

 //chart1.Series[1].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                            //chart1.Series[2].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";

                            //chart1.Series[3].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                            //chart1.Series[4].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";

Comment: Um, how does that zoom? Or do you mean you associate the series with a zoomed chartarea? that may result in zoomed data but the other areas' axis will not be zoomed. instead set their zoom properties (scaleview probably) to the same as the zoomed area1..

Comment: update the post